# uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details in compaling the code

Tags: android

Hello while compiling my app am getting an error like this.what is this warning am unable to finding an issue.
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

can any one please resolve the issues.In the below code have class named as selecttimeractivity simple it's showing unsafe operations and re-compile.

```
public class SelectTimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = SelectTimerActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @BindView(R.id.back)
    TextView mBack;
    @BindView(R.id.setTimer)
    TextView mSetTimer;
    @BindView(R.id.toolBar)
    Toolbar mToolBar;
    @BindView(R.id.customeSeekBar)
    RangeSeekBar mCustomeSeekBar;
    @BindView(R.id.dimming_picker)
    NumberPicker mDimmingPicker;

    private SharedPreferences mPref;
    private SolarBLEPacket mSolarBlePacket = new SolarBLEPacket();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_timer);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        final String[] dimmingValues = new String[]{"0%", "10%", "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "90%", "100%"};
        initDimmingPicker(dimmingValues);
        Long currentMin = 1L, currentMax = 66000L;
        mCustomeSeekBar.setRangeValues(currentMin, currentMax);
        attachColorToNumberPicker();
    }

    private void attachColorToNumberPicker() {
        int count = mDimmingPicker.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = mDimmingPicker.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof EditText) {
                try {
                    Field selectorWheelPaintField = mDimmingPicker.getClass()
                            .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                    selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
                    ((Paint) selectorWheelPaintField.get(mDimmingPicker)).setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    ((EditText) child).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    mDimmingPicker.invalidate();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void initDimmingPicker(String[] dimmingValues) {
        mDimmingPicker.setEnabled(true);
        mDimmingPicker.setMinValue(0);
        mDimmingPicker.setMaxValue(dimmingValues.length - 1);
        mDimmingPicker.setDisplayedValues(dimmingValues);
        mDimmingPicker.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        mDimmingPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.back, R.id.setTimer})
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.back:
                setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.setTimer:
                Number selectedMinValue = mCustomeSeekBar.getSelectedMinValue();
                Number selectedMaxValue = mCustomeSeekBar.getSelectedMaxValue();
                String timer1 = mCustomeSeekBar.convertSecondsToHMmSs(selectedMinValue.longValue());
                String timer2 = mCustomeSeekBar.getDiffTime(selectedMinValue.longValue(), selectedMaxValue.longValue());
                String timer1Command = buildDimDurnCmd(timer1);
                String timer2Command = builtDimmOffCommand(timer2);
                String brighnessCommand = builtBrightnessCommand();
                mPref.edit().putString(Constants.TIMER_ONE_CMD, timer1Command).commit();
                mPref.edit().putString(Constants.TIMER_TWO_CMD, timer2Command).commit();
                mPref.edit().putString(Constants.BRIGHTNESS_CMD, brighnessCommand).commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }

    private String builtBrightnessCommand() {
        final String[] dimmingValues = new String[]{"0%", "10%", "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "90%", "100%"};
        String dimmingValue = dimmingValues[mDimmingPicker.getValue()];
        String replacedString = dimmingValue.replace("%", "");
        String command = "";
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(replacedString)) {

            if (replacedString.length() == 1) {
                command = "bright 00" + replacedString;
            } else if (replacedString.length() == 2) {
                command = "bright 0" + replacedString;
            } else {
                command = "bright " + replacedString;
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "!! Built with Brightness Command...." + command);
        return mSolarBlePacket.generatePacket(command, "00");
    }

    private String buildDimDurnCmd(String command) {
        String[] commandArray = command.split(":");
        String hour = commandArray[0];
        String min = commandArray[1];
        String timerCommand = "dimdurn " + hour + "h" + min;
        Log.d(TAG, "!! Final Timer Command is " + timerCommand);
        return mSolarBlePacket.generatePacket(timerCommand, "00");
    }

    private String builtDimmOffCommand(String command) {
        String[] commandArray = command.split(":");
        String hour = commandArray[0];
        String min = commandArray[1];
        String timerCommand = "dimmoff " + hour + "h" + min;
        Log.d(TAG, "!! Final Timer Command is " + timerCommand);
        return mSolarBlePacket.generatePacket(timerCommand, "00");
    }
```

Comment: I guess Android Studio shows a warning as well on exactly the problematic operation.